# Identify udev subsystems and devtypes

Tags: usb, python, udev, usb-drive

I have to write a python script to monitor for usb mass storage devices. To successfully filter the required media it must be identified by its `subsystem` and `DEVTYPE`.

Does anyone know the required `subsystem` and `DEVTYPE` for a usb mass storage device?

Alternatively, can anyone tell me where I could find a list of all `subsystem`s and `DEVTYPE`s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I may have found the answer after some lurking in IRC for a while.

  ```
  SUBSYSTEM:block
  DEVTYPE:disk
  ```
- Here's how I found it. it was suggested this command:

  ```
  sudo udevadm info --root  --name=/dev/sdX
  ```

  Here 'X' in `sdX` must be replaced by the device that represents your USB mass storage device. If you need  to find that out, go to `/dev` and enter `ls`, once with the device connected to your machine and once without. Find the missing `sdX` and voila!

  This also shows properties such as `ID_FS_TYPE`, `ID_BUS` ,etc...
- However I'm not too sure about the `DEVTYPE` of USB mass storage devices. There's a chance it could be `partition`. If anyone knows, please comment or add an answer!

Comment: Thank you, nice to know about it. Seems OK, `DEVTYPE=partition` only if I point directly to the partition itself `/dev/sdXy` like: `/dev/sda1`